# This articles was --> closed

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using the following code:

```
import calendar
cal= calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=3)
for x in cal.iterweekdays():
    print(x)
```

Which shows the following result:

```
3 4 5 6 0 1 2
```

Can anyone explain what `iterweekdays()` function actually does?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.iterweekdays)? What in particular do you not understand?

Comment: I have read the  documentation for this function, but still, I can't understand. The link for the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar.iterweekdays

Comment: And *what* is it you don't understand? Maybe you could describe what you expected this function to do?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? Why did you choose this function and how does it not do what you want?

Comment: I am a beginner to python. So I just want to know what the function actually does

Comment: Do you not understand what an "iterator" is? Or what a "week day" is? Or how numbers are assigned to week days?

Comment: Yes! Can you explain iterator?

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) stated:

> **iterweekdays()**
>   Return an iterator for the week day numbers that will
>   be used for one week. The first value from the iterator will be the
>   same as the value of the *firstweekday* property.

Notice how the documentation says that the first value will be the same as defined in `firstweekday`. In your case: `firstweekday=3` and that why it goes from 3 to 6 and then 0, 1 and 2. In computer science it is usual to begin counting from 0.

It is hard to understand from your question, but in case you wish to display the names of the days you can use:

```
for x in cal.iterweekdays():
    calendar.day_name[x]
```

And you'll get in return:

```
'Thursday'
'Friday'
'Saturday'
'Sunday'
'Monday'
'Tuesday'
'Wednesday'
```

Answer (score 0):

> The iterweekdays() method returns an iterator for the weekday numbers that will be used for one week. The first number from the iterator will be the same as the number returned by firstweekday().

You have set 3 as start of the week.

Now iterweekdays(), print you all days in a week starting with day 3 so you get

```
3 4 5 6 0 1 2
```

Comment: Ok! I Think iterator is like as loop, So it's loop every time when it's got 7 days that it's stopped, I have one more doubt, I can use any string to here?

Comment: I recommend learning basic Python syntax first. You are trying to do something, but you have no clue what and how to do it, so neither do we. Try describing your problem instead of asking what function X does.